# Unfocusing all EditTexts on the screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I have an XML layout with 20-25 similar rows which are used to set different parameters. The rows contain an `AutoCompleteTextView` and an `ImageButton`. Whenever an option is set within one of these views, a method is called to set the variable in my code, and then refresh all of the views. There are three ways each variable can be set...`AutoCompleteTextView:` OnKeyListener, OnItemSelectedListener....`ImageButton:` OnClickListener

Here is an example of this part of one of the rows:

```
pumpCountAutoText = new AutoCompleteTextView( this );
pumpCountAutoText.setHint( R.string.anti_pump_pump_count_hint );
pumpCountAutoText.setTextSize( 12.0f );
pumpCountAutoText.setLayoutParams( editLP );
pumpCountAutoText.setThreshold( 1 );
pumpCountAutoText.setId( 11001 );
pumpCountAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pumpCountList);
pumpCountAutoText.setAdapter( pumpCountAdapter );
pumpCountAutoText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                String item = pumpCountAutoText.getText().toString();
                hideSoftKeyboard( MoreParameters.this );
                pumpCountAutoText.dismissDropDown();
                if( hasRead ) {
                    if(pumpCountList.contains( item ) ) {
                         if( !( item.equals( " " ) ) ) {
                                int val = Integer.parseInt( item );
                                //Log.i( "pumpCountSpinner", Integer.toString( val ) );
                                RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls.SetParmJava( RelayAPIModel.PARM_PUMPCOUNT, val );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
         });
        pumpCountAutoText.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hideSoftKeyboard( MoreParameters.this );
                String item = pumpCountAutoText.getText().toString();
                if( !( item.equals( " " ) ) ) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt( item );
                    //Log.i( "pumpCountSpinner", Integer.toString( val ) );
                    RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls.SetParmJava( RelayAPIModel.PARM_PUMPCOUNT, val );
                }
            }

        });


        pumpCountDropdownButton = new ImageButton( this );
        pumpCountDropdownButton.setLayoutParams( dropLP );
        pumpCountDropdownButton.setId( 11002 );
        pumpCountDropdownButton.setImageResource( R.drawable.arrow_down_float );
        pumpCountDropdownButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreParameters.this);
                ab.setTitle( R.string.anti_pump_pump_count_hint );
                ab.setItems( pumpCountList.toArray( new String[pumpCountList.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos ) {
                        String item = pumpCountList.get( pos );
                        if( !( item.equals( " " ) ) ) {
                            int val = Integer.parseInt( item );
                            RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls.SetParmJava( RelayAPIModel.PARM_PUMPCOUNT, val );
                        }
                    }
                });
                ab.show();
            }

        });
```

My problem is that after any of these items are set, the text field at the top of my screen automatically gets focused and displays the dropdown menu for that view. It is extremely annoying. I want to select an item in any view and not have these dropdowns appear.

I have tried two things:

1) I have added AutoCompleteTextView.setCursorVisible( false );

2) And I have also tried this:

```
specialCTAutoText.setFocusable( false );
specialCTAutoText.setFocusableInTouchMode( false );
specialCTAutoText.setText( temp );
specialCTAutoText.setFocusable( true );
specialCTAutoText.setFocusableInTouchMode( true );
```

The second thing I tried is called when all of my views are refreshed in the second method which is not shown here. This works fine. However, once I edit a textview one of those three ways, it still auto selects the top edittext view.

I hope this is clear enough, but any clarification needed let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly undestand you but did you try having an invisible (via _visibility_) input filed and request the focus for that?

Comment: No I don't think so. Everything works fine there are no errors or anything. Its just that in a column of edit text fields, if I click one and edit it using any of the three listeners shown above, I expect the screen to default back to nothing selected. However, the `AutoCompleteTextView` on the top gains a cursor and shows a dropdown menu from it.

Comment: See? @CommonsWare made ther same suggestion as I did.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, once I edit a textview one of those three ways, it still auto selects the top edittext view.

Try calling `requestFocus()` on some other widget at the point in time when you "edit a textview one of those three ways".

Comment: OK I will try it, but i'm a little confused. This seems like it may work but it doesn't seem proper. I can just call requestFocus on any view at all? I have TextViews that are never changed or touched in every row as well. Would I be able to just call requestFocus( TextView )? I will try this now but it doesn't seem too clean.

Comment: @JuiCe: "I can just call requestFocus on any view at all?" -- well, I'd choose one that can have the focus. If you have no focusable widgets other than the one you are complaining about, please allow that widget to be focused as it is currently, as it *needs* to be focused for use by people who do not use touchscreens (e.g., blind users with devices with arrow keys/D-pad/trackball).

Comment: hmm ok. Thanks for the info. I will not have any users who do not use touch screens but I understand where you're coming from. I really just want to get rid of the dropdown menu that pops up as it doesn't feel clean when I set one variable and another one randomly shows a dropdown menu. Maybe removing focus isn't what I needed.

Comment: @JuiCe: "I will not have any users who do not use touch screens" -- how will you prevent a blind user from downloading and using your app?  "I really just want to get rid of the dropdown menu that pops up as it doesn't feel clean when I set one variable and another one randomly shows a dropdown menu" -- most likely, that is the first focusable widget in your UI.

Comment: Well the application will be pre-installed on hardware, not available for download. You are correct in saying it is the first focusable widget in the UI. This may seem repetitive, but you're saying theres no way to have nothing focused?